# design a look-up data-structure by dictionary in C#, but got error

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, data-structures, dictionary

I am working with C# on Win 7 Visual Studio 2012.

I am desinging a data structure that can store information about some cards.

Each card may have one or more personeName, and each operson may have a value.

The card number may be ten thousands.

I am trying to use dictionary to implement the data structure. 
Because I need to lookup the card to update/add the persons and values, I use dictionary.

I need to populate the dictionary by loading data from a txt file.

The key is a string that represent a card and the values is string[ string[] ] because each card my have different persons.

So, string[0]  will hold a value for person 1 and so on. And, each person may have a value stored in string[i].[0].  The values of each person in a card may be used for sorting or other operations.

But, C# does not allow me to implemnt it in this way:

```
 Dictionary<string, string[string[]]> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string[string[]]>();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try Dictionary<string, List<string[]>> myDict. string[string[]] does not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you could elaborate on "does not allow me to", does it give you an error and what did that error tell you?

I think you could benefit from a different design though. You should not have to model your business logic to your data model. How you fill the object I'll leave to you, but take a look at this approach. If you declare a `Card` class as such:

```
public class Card
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public IList<string> PersonsHoldingThisCard { get; private set; }

    public Card(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        PersonsHoldingThisCard = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

You can store instances of it in a `HashSet<Card>`, which has great lookup speeds, and the list allows for easy additions and removal of names of persons holding that particular card compared to your array.

If you mean you need to look up cards by name, you can use a `Dictionary<string, Card>`.

I'm not sure whether you want to actually use this approach or rather want to declare a `Player` with a `List<string> CardsInHand` property, but I think that depends on what you want your program to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have the syntax incorrect. Try:

```
Dictionary<string, string[][]> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string[][]>();
```

However, you may want to use a class for the card itself rather than a string array if most cards will contain the same information. This makes your code more readable and, if you have any card specific methods, allows you to include them in that object (called encapsulation).

If you are adding or removing fields to the cards, arrays will be inefficient because they have a fixed size, too. Consider a `Collection<string>` or `List<string>`.

Alternatively, if the cards are going to have varying information or a lot of fields, have a Dictionary of Dictionaries, e.g.:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> myDict = 
    new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>>();
```